# Does this type of colloquial compound adjective translate directly: "got-rejected dance"

Tags: translation, adverbs, adjectives

做我被拒绝的舞蹈! Doing my "got-rejected" dance!

---

Final answer:

被拒绝后，我气得直跺脚跳 "我被拒绝后的舞蹈!"

Comment: Is "Doing my got rejected dance!" idiomatic English? 做我被拒绝的舞蹈!  is not correct Chinese.

Comment: "Got Rejected" dance. It's a dance you do to counteract the effects of rejection

Comment: In English, it uses a [compound adjective](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Compound-Adjectives.htm), which is usually indicated by a hyphen: "Doing my got-rejected dance!"

Answer (score 2):

Not colloquial, normal.

跳他们不让我表演的舞蹈。
Dance the dance which they would not let me perform.

[relative clause]

A relative clause is an extended, trailing adjective. Chinese knows no relative clauses. Chinese puts these kind of things first. Case considerations precluded the use of such adjectives before nouns in Western languages.

Dance the [which they would not let me perform] dance.

Dance the dance [(which) they would not let me perform].

跳 [他们不让我表演的] 舞蹈。

Ah, well, in that case:

I stamped my feet in anger at my rejection. = I danced my "I've-been-rejected" dance.

被拒绝后，我气得直跺脚.

Comment: Hi! It's a dance you do after you got rejected. For example, suppose you got rejected from a date or from your dream school. Some people cry, some people dance!

Comment: That was none too clear from your post!

Comment: thank you for explaining the different variants!

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct Chinese phrase to express this. It's a culture thing. We don't usually dance as an counteraction of rejection.

In Chinese, we'd probably say 我的表白被拒了(My confession of love has been rejected)，我要去跳舞发泄一下(I will go dance to blow off some steam)。

Comment: i don't think anyone usually dances due to rejection. but sometimes it helps to counteract its effects. better than crying.

Comment: how would you say it if you were to name a dance "got rejected" in Chinese

Comment: @ina In this case, you can invent one. :) It could be something like 被拒舞 for example.

Answer (score 1):

> 做我被拒绝的舞蹈!
>   Doing my got-rejected dance!

#### Grammar problems

1. [做](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%81%9A) ("to do") is mismatched with [舞蹈](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%88%9E%E8%B9%88) ("dance"); it should be [跳](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%B7%B3), as in [跳舞](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%B7%B3%E8%88%9E) ("to dance").  My impression is that using 做 sounds like you're *inventing* a new dance (here 做 = "to make"), e.g.:

   > [舞团](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%88%9E%E5%9B%A2)刚**做的新舞蹈**，跳出别样的[舞姿](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%88%9E%E5%A7%BF)，是我[向往](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%90%91%E5%BE%80)的生活 ([source](https://haokan.baidu.com/v?pd=wisenatural&vid=4650635562047153801)).
   >   [The] dance group just invented a new dance, and performs different kind of positions; it's the life I yearn for.  (my translation)
2. We need to indicate that the rejection happened in the past.  This can be done using [completion 了](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_completion_with_%22le%22), or with [后](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%90%8E) or [以后](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BB%A5%E5%90%8E) (see: [After a specific time with "yihou"](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/After_a_specific_time_with_%22yihou%22)).  Such as in:

   > [相亲](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%9B%B8%E4%BA%B2)**被拒绝了的**感受是什么呢？ ([source](https://know.baidu.com/question/06847ca8beb5c5173fd2adb31dfd423807f5dd1))
   >   What are the blind-date post-rejection feelings?
   >
   > 谈谈[邀请](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%82%80%E8%AF%B7/)女士跳舞**被拒绝后的**心里感受 ([source](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/ca5cad3780eb6294dc886c36.html))
   >   Discuss post-[inviting a woman to dance and being rejected] feelings

   In this case, I feel 后 is a more natural choice: it feels more immediate, and like a reaction to the rejection.

Thus, the original Chinese says something like "inventing a my-rejection dance".  I believe fixing these points gives the correct meaning:

> **跳**我被拒绝**后**的舞蹈！
>   Doing my post-rejection dance!

However, this seems outside of the Chinese cultural sphere and might not be easy to understand [this happens a lot!], and seems why the other answers focus on giving alternatives.